# remove permanetly wordpress post from core wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create a super lightweight WordPress admin only the possibility to create pages and using 2/3 plugins.

I would like to speed up WordPress by removing all unecessary things that I dont usually use on my websites.

My first question is : Is there any lightweight Wordpress fork ? Which still allow using the plugins.

If no, then my second question is : How to definitly remove the posts section ? Since i'm not using posts at all, I would like to delete it (not just hide it) from Wordpress.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1):

You can use `remove_menu_page()` to remove admin menus. Somehow like this:

```
<?php
function remove_menus(){

  remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
  remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );                    //Jetpack* 
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
  remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
  remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
  remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
  remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
  remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
  remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
  remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I dont only want to remove them from the menu, I want to demove the code from Wordpress Core, so that any of it will be charged, and i'm convinced that this will lighten wordpress.

Comment: @Yacine why would you want that? Is it because of the performance? You can customize the backend by removing items that you don't need and they are not going to be loaded. If you care about the frontend, you just need to customize your theme. Anyway, there is no official light version of Wordpress.

Comment: Yeah because of the performance + SEO purpose. 

In fact, I dont want Wordpress to generate unused pages (tags, archives, categories ...)

I dont want neither those sections to be loaded, so that the whole thing is way less heavy.

I know there is no light version of wordpress (unfortunatly), but may be is there somewhere on github someone who already did that job ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Yacine if you care about the frontend, none of the features will be loaded as soon as your theme won't include them. A lighter version of Wordpress has definitely nothing to do with the performance and SEO of your frontend. So what you need is not a lighter version of Wordpress but a light version of a theme! Also if you care about performance, you shouldn't use ANY plugins at all. The best performance you get by using your own code.